# Private method inception in jython

Tags: java, python, jython

this is my first question in this forum, I've been searching with no luck for my case.

the call hierarchy is as follow:

```
public class ClassA {
    private methodA() {
            a = methodB()
    return a
    }

    private methodB(){
           b =  methodC()
    return b
    }

    private methodC(){
       c = 5 + 1
    return c
    }
}
```

all of methods are in the same class

I invoke the private method A using following code in jython:

```
m = object.class.getDeclaredMethod("methodA")
m.setAccessible(True)
m.invoke(object)
```

the question is will the the setAccessible modifier propagated to other private method. and all method will be successfully return the expected value?

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know jython for sure. But it seems that m is identical with your methodA.
If you set m (or methodA respectively) to be accessible you will not set methodB accessible.

But as you can now call methodA, this method has no problem calling other private methods from its own class.

Comment: so you are saying if the methodA was successfully called without any error that means this method is internally manage to call all private method inside  of it, yes?

Comment: I would say you just changed the acces modifier from private to public for this one method. The method itself always has the right to call private methods of its own class.

Comment: If methodA were public to begin with, would you be able to call methodA and have methodA successfully call methodB on your behalf? Yes. Same thing is true with reflection. You just have to make your entry point accessible, then the house is yours to raid.